# ggplot customize legend for geom_point shapes and remove background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks something like this:

```
df = data.frame(
  measure = c("Measure A","Measure B","Measure C","Measure D",
              "Measure E","Measure F","Measure G"),
  overall = c(56, 78, 19, 87, 45, 51, 19),
  company = c(45, 89, 18, 98, 33, 55, 4),
  company_p = c(32, 65, 5, 56, 12, 45, 10)
)
```

Using this code:

```
ggplot(df %>% 
         mutate(fill = ifelse(overall > company, " Below Overall  "," Above Overall  ")), 
       aes(measure)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=company, fill= fill)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=overall, color="overall"), size=6, shape=124) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=company_p, color="company_p"), size=2, shape=19) +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red4","grey3"),labels=c("Company Last Year","Overall")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(" Below Overall  "="lightpink2",
                             " Above Overall  "="lightblue2")) +
  theme(legend.key=element_blank())
```

I get a graph that looks like this:

[image]

How do I set the legend so that the company_p values, or 'Company Last Year' on the legend looks like the corresponding shape, while the Overall looks like a black line?

I tried linking the shape type to the legend like this:

```
ggplot(df %>% 
         mutate(fill = ifelse(overall > company, " Below Overall  "," Above Overall  ")), 
       aes(measure)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=company, fill= fill)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=overall, color="overall"), size=6, shape="overall") + 
  geom_point(aes(y=company_p, color="company_p"), size=2, shape="company_p") +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(overall=124, company_p=19)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red4","grey3"),labels=c("Company Last Year","Overall")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(" Below Overall  "="lightpink2",
                             " Above Overall  "="lightblue2")) +
  theme(legend.key=element_blank())
```

[image]

But the shape symbols don't correlate to the reference (124 is |, 19 is a circle) and it seems the shapes are together in the legend, not separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I reshaped the data with `tidyr` to combine the two columns at issue. Since you want the points with different color, size, and shape you need to include all of those in the `aes()` for `geom_point`, and then you can use `scale_` functions with the same `name` argument. I named it `Legend` but you can change that to whatever makes sense.

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% mutate(fill = ifelse(overall > company, " Below Overall  "," Above Overall  ")) %>%
  gather(key, val, -company, -measure, -fill)

ggplot(df2, aes(measure)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=company, fill= fill), data = df2[!duplicated(df2$measure),]) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(" Below Overall  "="lightpink2"," Above Overall  "="lightblue2")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=val, shape=key, color = key, size = key), data = df2) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values=c("red4", "grey3"), labels = c("Company Last Year", "Overall")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Legend", values = c(19, 124), labels = c("Company Last Year", "Overall")) +
  scale_size_manual(name = "Legend", values = c(2, 6), labels = c("Company Last Year", "Overall")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Might pop in the second legend name for them: scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend_2", values=c(" Below Overall  "="lightpink2"," Above Overall  "="lightblue2")) +